# How to make the constructor produce null if a certain condition reaches?

Tags: c#

For academic purposes, I provide the following example. Unconditionally creating an instance of `Exercise` as a property will trigger overflow at runtime. So I have to check the number of instance in the ctor. I think there are many way to do so but here I want to focus on the ctor only.

## Question

Is it possible to  make the constructor produce `null` if `counter>9`? If yes, how to do so?

```
class Exercise
{
    Exercise e = new Exercise();
    static int counter = 0;
    public Exercise()
    {
        //if (++counter > 9)
        // return null;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Exercise e = new Exercise();
    }
}
```

Comment: `trigger overflow at runtime` why do you think that would happen? If you keep `Exercise e = new Exercise();` in your class then surely Overflow will happen. you should remove `Exercise e = new Exercise();`

Comment: As far as I know, no. In C#, a constructor doesn't return anything, it merely initializes a fully allocated object. When you invoke `new` memory is allocated and that memory is passed to the constructor for initialization. One way around this is to make the constructor private and have that logic in a public static factory method (say `public static Exercise CreateExercise()`

Comment: The constructor can't return `null`. It can return an object, or throw an exception. They are your two options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Constructors should always create a valid object and the language tries to enforce this by not allowing you to return null from a constructor. You can use the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#) and encapsulate the creation of the object.

```
public class ExerciseFactory {
  static int counter = 0;


  public static GetExercise() {
    if (counter > 9) return null;
    counter++
    return new Exercise();
  }

}
```

Comment: +1, though you could also put `GetExercise()` in the `Exercise` class instead of a separate factory class.

Answer (score 2):

You could use factory methods to implement this. The following exmaple is running in LinqPad, hence the `Dump()` method. You'd have to replace this with a Console.WriteLine or any other output method suitable to you:

```
void Main()
{
    var exerciseList = new List<Exercise>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Exercise e = Exercise.Create();
        exerciseList.Add(e);            
    }
    exerciseList.Count(x => x != null).Dump();
}

public class Exercise
{
    private static int _counter = 0;
    private Exercise()
    {
    }

    public static Exercise Create() 
    {
        if (_counter > 8)
        {
            //or throw exception?
            return null;
        }
        else {
            _counter++;
            return new Exercise();

        }
    }
}
```

One thing to note here is, that the constructor is private, so nobody could circumvent the limitation, solely by not calling `Create`. This way you can not new-up a new instance by using the `new` keyword.